# Embed Windows Media Player with visualization disabled

Tags: embed, windows-media-player

I'm working in a corporate environment where the primary mechanism of media playback is Windows Media Player. On our intranet we're serving MP3 files in an embedded WMP through Internet Explorer 6.

I have no problems with embedding, playback, etc. The only issue is that I want to disable the visualization that is automatically turned on when I'm playing back an MP3.

**Note**: I'd love to, but can't use an alternative in this case. Please don't suggest one.

Here's a sample of what my current embedding code looks like, it's very slim and only works in IE. I'm working on updating it to be cross-browser, but that isn't in the requirements right now so it's a low priority.

```
<object id="PLAYER" type="application/x-oleobject" height="360" width="480" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
  <param value="sb-sou-3-09.mp3" name="Url" />
</object>
```

Ideally I'd like to retain the playback controls, but just turn the visualization off. If it's a big black rectangle, that's fine. Our users don't need the illusion that they are flying through a tunnel of sound -- they just want to listen to the audio.

I've tried setting the `uiMode` setting, but [none of the possible values listed at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564089(VS.85).aspx) are the ones I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

try fiddling with the height i.e.

```
<object classid="clsid:6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6" height="45" width="250">
    <param name="URL" value="reagan-audio.mp3" />
    <param name="uimode" value="full" />
</object>
```

Comment: notice the trick here is to use `<param name="uimode" value="full" />`, this way the `height` attribute works